# Google Analytics and Masterpage/User Control swapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, google-analytics

I'm using GA on my site and need to add tracking to a several pages. These pages are rendered by means of a master page in conjunction with a Telerik tab control. When a tab is selected, the code evaluates which tab was clicked and inserts the appropriate user control for that page and rerenders it. According to the browser, it's always default.aspx but the ascx in it is different.

How could I track the different pages with this sort of setup?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

1. Make sure the google analytics tracking fires at the end of the page being fully rendered
2. Have the ASCXs set a global "page_name" variable (this should be initialized somewhere in your master view, i'd imagine) with some unique name that lets you know what the ascx is
3. Use one of the google analytics track overloads that allows you to supply the page name (I don't have an example handy, but you should be able to find one easily). Use the global "page_name" variable as the page name

This isn't the cleanest most proper solution, but WebForms can often dictate less-than-beautiful solutions... This would be the simplest, easiest to implement change I can think of.